# auto complete textbox from scratch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am writing autocomplete input control from scratch using javascript and jquery. I know I can use the jquery autocomplete. But then there won't be any fun.

The autocomplete I have so far shows suggestions but I am not able to select the suggestions using mouse. How can I do this?

The code I have so far is following html,

```
<div class="sug">
<input type="text" id="auto" onkeyup="display(event)" onblur="hide()" autocomplete="off" />
<div class="suggestion" id="suggestion">
</div>
</div>
```

and following is the style sheet

```
<style>
.suggestion
{
    border:solid 2px black;
}
.sug > .suggestion
{
    display:none;
}
.sug > .suggestion,#auto
{
    width:100px;
}
}
</style>
```

and my javascript code is following

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    var array = new Array();
    array.push("heena");
    array.push("bhawin");
    array.push("aruna");
    array.push("mahesh");
    array.push("anshul");
    array.push("jagruti");
    array.push("neha");
    array.push("sherry");
    array.push("sonali");
    var data;
    var id; //for providing id to each div
    function display(e)
    {


        if (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40)
        {
            selectit(e);
        }
        data = "";
        id = 0;
        var state = $('#auto').val();
        if (state == "")//value empty
        {
            $('.suggestion').css({ display: "none" });
        }
        else
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            {
                var key = 0;
                for (j = 0; j < state.length; j++)
                {
                    //for the matching of the array element with the text in the textbox
                    if (array[i][j] == state[j])
                    {
                        key++;
                    }
                }
                //putting the matched array element in a div
                if (key == state.length)
                {
                    //the whole array will be copied with the bold values inserted
                    var bolde = "";
                    for (var k = 0; k < key; k++)
                    {
                        bolde += "" + array[i][k] + "";
                    }
                    for (var l = key; l < array[i].length; l++)
                    {
                        bolde += array[i][l];
                    }
                    id++;
                    data += "<div id='" + id + "'>" + bolde + "</div>";
                }
            }
            $('.suggestion').html(data);
            $('.suggestion').css({ display: "block" });
            selectit(e);
            if (data == "")
            {
                $('.suggestion').css({ display: "none" });
            }
        }
    }
    function hide()
    {
        $('#suggestion').css({ display: "none" }); ;
    }
    function selectit(e)
    {
        var child = document.getElementById("suggestion").childNodes;

        for (var i = 0; i < child.length; i++)
        {

            if (child[i].id == "1")
            {
                child[i].style.color = "red";   //here is the problem in the code
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: It doesnt show up any suggestions

Comment: I don't know how to use fiddle

Comment: @user3168736 you need to add jquery

Comment: @xyz Go to [JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/), put your HTML code in the HTML box and so on, and when all your code is in that page, hit the "Run" button at the top to see the result. If you're ready, click "Save"/"Update" and copy/paste the link here. Like this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26NK9/1/)

Comment: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/WJ3Z5/) No suggestions yet

Comment: @user3168736 it's still not working fiddle

Answer (score 0):

there was two problems

**ONE :** 
you need to take off the `hide();` from `onblur`

```
<div class="sug">
<input type="text" id="auto" onkeyup="display(event)" autocomplete="off" /><!--i changed here to Note the on blur-->
<div class="suggestion" id="suggestion">
</div>
</div>
```

**TWO :**  set the `onclick` of the div and use `hide();` in it

```
<script>
 var array = new Array();
    array.push("heena");
    array.push("bhawin");
    array.push("aruna");
    array.push("mahesh");
    array.push("anshul");
    array.push("jagruti");
    array.push("neha");
    array.push("sherry");
    array.push("sonali");
    var data;
    var id;
    function display(e)
    {


        if (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40)
        {
            selectit(e);
        }
        data = "";
        id = 0;
        var state = $('#auto').val();
        if (state == "")
        {
            $('.suggestion').css({ "display": "none" });
        }
        else
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            {
                var key = 0;
                for (j = 0; j < state.length; j++)
                {
                    if (array[i][j] == state[j])
                    {
                        key++;
                    }
                }
                if (key == state.length)
                {
                    var bolde = "";
                    for (var k = 0; k < key; k++)
                    {
                        bolde += "" + array[i][k] + "";
                    }
                    for (var l = key; l < array[i].length; l++)
                    {
                        bolde += array[i][l];
                    }
                    id++;
                    data += '<div id="' + id + '" onclick="$(\'#auto\').val(this.innerHTML);hide();" >' + bolde + "</div>";// i changed here note the on click
                }
            }
            $('.suggestion').html(data);
            $('.suggestion').css({ "display": "block" });
            selectit(e);
            if (data == "")
            {
                $('.suggestion').css({ "display": "none" });
            }
        }
    }
    function hide()
    {
        $('#suggestion').css({ "display" : "none" }); ;
    }
    function selectit(e)
    {
        var child = document.getElementById("suggestion").childNodes;

        for (var i = 0; i < child.length; i++)
        {

            if (child[i].id == "1")
            {
                child[i].style.color = "red"; 
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: TWO : set the onclik of the div and use hdie(); in it. 
`onclik`, `hdie()` correct this first

Comment: @Youness what if I want suggestion selection using mouse's up and down arrow keys?

Comment: then i will have to add some code ;) lol you need that feature ?

Comment: @Youness actually yes I need that feature. And thanks :)